# How to customize FCKEditor to use FONT instead of SPAN style?

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to use a ColdFusion`<cftextarea richedit="true">`  tag that uses FCKEditor 2.x, to feed into a textfield in `<cfreportparam>` which only understands the `<FONT>` tag, not the `<span style="">` that FCKEditor 2.x generates.

How can I customize `fckconfig.js` to have FCKEditor 2.x generates `<FONT face="" size="" color="">` ??

This link should be related: http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Configuration/Configuration_Options/CoreStyles

Thank you

Comment: Font tags are deprecated. You should probably look for a newer/better component to interpret styles. It shouldn't be too hard to find an HTML parser, and you might be able to get by with some quick splitting on semicolons to parse the CSS.

Comment: I know it is deprecated, but the ancient old ColdFusion Report Builder  only understands the <font> tag...

Comment: Well, you could potentially use an HTML parser on the server to convert the fckeditor input into the syntax you need with <font> tags.

Comment: @coreyward hmm... seems overkill, I guess I'll have to resort to your idea if FCKEditor 2.x really can't generate <font>, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!  Append the following code to `fckconfig.js`

```
FCKConfig.CoreStyles['FontFace'] = 
{ 
    Element     : 'font', 
    Attributes : { 'face' : '#("Font")' }
};
FCKConfig.CoreStyles['Size'] = 
{ 
    Element     : 'font', 
    Attributes : { 'size' : '#("Size","fontSize")' }
};
FCKConfig.CoreStyles['Color'] = 
{ 
    Element     : 'font', 
    Attributes : { 'color' : '#("Color","color")' }
};
FCKConfig.FontSizes = '1/xx-small;2/x-small;3/small;4/medium;5/large;6/x-large;7/xx-large' ;
```

source: http://drupal.fckeditor.net/filters